# ATMEGA 2560 uart code not giving out correct output on minicom

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, uart, atmega

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define BAUDRATE 115200
#define BAUD_PRESCALLER (((F_CPU / (BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)

//Declaration of our functions
void USART_init(void);
unsigned char USART_receive(void);
void USART_send( unsigned char data);

int main(void){
USART_init();        //Call the USART initialization code

while(1){        //Infinite loop
 USART_send('A');
 _delay_ms(1000);        //Delay for 5 seconds so it will re-send the string every 5 seconds
 }

return 0;
}

void USART_init(void){

 UBRR1H = (uint8_t)(BAUD_PRESCALLER>>8);
 UBRR1L = (uint8_t)(BAUD_PRESCALLER);
 UCSR1B = (1<<RXEN1)|(1<<TXEN1);
 UCSR1C = (3<<UCSZ10);
}

unsigned char USART_receive(void){

 while(!(UCSR1A & (1<<RXC1)));
 return UDR1;

}

void USART_send( unsigned char data){

 while(!(UCSR1A & (1<<UDRE1)));
 UDR1 = data;

}
```

minicom on Ubuntu set to 115200 8N1

I am using Elegoo ATMEGA2560, TX1 and RX1 and GND pins from communication port. https://github.com/enthusiasticgeek/Elegoo_Mega_2560

I intend to send 'A' from ATMEGA and expect to see it on minicom on PC. But I am receiving  ' _ ' on minicom. I changed the minicom setting to 115200 7N1 and still receiving ' _ '. Then I changed to 115200 6N1 then I get a different binary character. I tried changing minicom settings but to no avail. Any idea what I am going wrong?

This is what I am seeing when I send different characters.

**Expected (AVR sends)**   ASCII 0x56 [01010110]  (V)

**Observed (PC receives)** ASCII 0x2A [00101010]  (*)

**Expected (AVR sends)**   ASCII 0x41 [01000001]  (A)

**Observed (PC receives)** ASCII 0x5F [01011111]  (_)

**Expected (AVR sends)**   ASCII 0x42 [01000010]  (B)

**Observed (PC receives)** ASCII 0x2F [00101111]  (/)

**Expected (AVR sends)**   ASCII 0x55 [01010101]  (U)

**Observed (PC receives)** ASCII 0x55 [01010101]  (U)

Here are my fuse settings https://github.com/enthusiasticgeek/Elegoo_Mega_2560/blob/master/avrdude.conf

```
    memory "lfuse"
    size            = 1;
    write           = "1 0 1 0  1 1 0 0  1 0 1 0  0 0 0 0",
                      "x x x x  x x x x  i i i i  i i i i";

    read            = "0 1 0 1  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0",
                      "x x x x  x x x x  o o o o  o o o o";
    min_write_delay = 9000;
    max_write_delay = 9000;
      ;

    memory "hfuse"
    size            = 1;
    write           = "1 0 1 0  1 1 0 0  1 0 1 0  1 0 0 0",
                      "x x x x  x x x x  i i i i  i i i i";

    read            = "0 1 0 1  1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  1 0 0 0",
                      "x x x x  x x x x  o o o o  o o o o";
    min_write_delay = 9000;
    max_write_delay = 9000;
      ;

    memory "efuse"
    size            = 1;
    write           = "1 0 1 0  1 1 0 0  1 0 1 0  0 1 0 0",
                      "x x x x  x x x x  x x x x  x i i i";

    read            = "0 1 0 1  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  1 0 0 0",
                      "x x x x  x x x x  o o o o  o o o o";
    min_write_delay = 9000;
    max_write_delay = 9000;
;
```

Here is what happens when I load the fw

```
avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega2560 -c -o test.o test.c
avr-gcc -mmcu=atmega2560 test.o -o test
#EEPROM
#avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom test test.hex
#FLASH
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .flash test test.hex
sudo avrdude -c wiring -p m2560 -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -V -U flash:w:test.hex -D

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9801 (probably m2560)
avrdude: reading input file "test.hex"
avrdude: input file test.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (366 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.08s

avrdude: 366 bytes of flash written

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FD, H:D8, L:FF)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Note: I am using CP-US-03 serial adapter which I assume would have FTD232 chip. I also get the same results from the Arduino sketch using the code

```
void setup() {

// initialize both serial ports:
Serial1.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {

// read from port 1, send to port 0:
//if (Serial1.available()) {
//  int inByte = Serial1.read();
//  Serial.write(inByte);
//
 }

// read from port 0, send to port 1:
//if (Serial1.available()) {
  int inByte = 0x41;//Serial.read();
  Serial1.write(inByte);
  delay(1000);
//}
}
```

Hence, now I have started to look if this is TTL or logic level conversion issue.

Comment: Quadruple-check USART_init() against user manual.  Then send 0x55 continually, scope the output, measure the bit-width/time and calculate what the real baud rate is that you are using.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for the suggestion. I will try and obtain an oscilloscope in next 2-3 days and keep you posted on the results.

Comment: Where is F_CPU defined in your code and what is its value? Also what is the actual clock speed of  the MCU?

Comment: @BenceKaulics F_CPU is in Makefile. https://github.com/enthusiasticgeek/Elegoo_Mega_2560/blob/master/Makefile  Actual clockspeed is 16MHz per Elegoo ATMEGA 2560 board.

Comment: Hello, the refence manual for your controller says that recommended error for the receiver in normal speed mode and 8 bit data + 0 parity bit is +-2% (table 22-2) and your actual settings (16Mhz, normal speed, 8 bit data + 0 parity bit, 115.2K baudrate) give the error of -3.5% (table 22-12). Try using the baudrate that gives lesser error e.g. 76.8K.

Comment: @nopasara 9600 baud yields same results at higher baud rate.

Comment: @enthusiasticgeek And what are the values of the fuse bits set on your controller?

Comment: @nopasara See my Makefile https://github.com/enthusiasticgeek/Elegoo_Mega_2560/blob/master/Makefile which uses https://github.com/enthusiasticgeek/Elegoo_Mega_2560/blob/master/avrdude.conf All the fuse bits defined there for m2560 including lfuse, hfuse and efuse

Comment: @enthusiasticgeek well, you're mistaking those are only commands for programming fuse bits not the values (refer Table 30-17 of the controller's manual) actual fuse bits values you may read by issuing those commands like -U lfuse:r:lfuse.hex:i and also they need to be set explicitly after you flash the controller

Comment: i mean not every time but you may need to set fuse bits

Comment: @nopasara I added `-U lfuse:w:0xff:m -U hfuse:w:0xD8:m -U efuse:w:0xfd:m` to the avrdude command line but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was nothing related to my code. I ended up ordering the following USB 2.0 to TTL UART 6PIN CP2102 Module Serial Converter and everything was hunky dory.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01LRVQIFQ/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LRVQIFQ)

The regular USB to serial CP-US-03 wouldn't work.